# Affiliation for publication

Tags: publications, affiliation

I recently got accepted into one of the schools in Europe. According to the anticipated date mentioned in the offer letter, my studies will start in Dec 2017. Now, the problem is that I've got two papers ready for submission at the moment and I don't have the faintest idea what to put for my affiliation. Any ideas?

Just to clarify that this question is not a duplicate:
When I was working on the above-mentioned studies, I was not either employed by or affiliated with my former university. My former supervisor did help me out with some parts of the papers, but rather as a colleague or a friend than as a "supervisor" in the true sense of the word.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a common practice as your affiliation you use the one that you had during performing the work. This is especially true when you do not have new affiliation. For example, a PhD student that publishes his/her PhD paper while he/she is already two years into a postdoc. Many people will still leave the PhD affiliation, probably also add new one. Otherwise, it will look weird that affiliation of your and your advisor is different.

Comment: _Otherwise, it will look weird that affiliation of your and your advisor is different._ — No, it'll just look like you graduated.

Comment: When two authors have completely different affiliations this looks as though they are just collaborators....Obviously, all this does not matter much